# VBA code to find the largest negative value < 0 in a range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for a code to find out the largest negative value < 0 in a range.

I know the function Max, tryed it, but didn't work well to attend my problem.

I have a code ready to search different ranges, now I need to find the largest negative value on that range.

Comment: Did you maybe try `MIN` instead?

Comment: Excel formulas might be the most concise approach.  `=MAX(IF(A1:G10<0, A1:G10))` assumming data range is A1:G10.

Comment: By "largest negative" do you mean, the most negative or the least negative?

Comment: Please, try a much more compact solution: `Function maxNegativeNo(rng As Range) As Double` `Dim arrNeg: arrNeg = Evaluate("IF(" & rng.address & "<0," & rng.address(0, 0) & ","""")")`  `maxNegativeNo = Application.Max(arrNeg)`  `End Function`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Get Max Negative

[image]

**The Test (Usage)**

```vb
Sub GetMaxNegativeTEST()
    
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Sheet1.Range("A2:A11,C2:C11,E2:E11")
    
    Dim MaxNegative As Double: MaxNegative = GetMaxNegative(rg)
    
    If MaxNegative = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No negative values found.", _
            vbExclamation
    Else
        MsgBox "The maximum negative value is " & MaxNegative & ".", _
            vbInformation ' Screenshot Result = -3
    End If

End Sub
```

**The Function**

```vb
Function GetMaxNegative(ByVal rg As Range) As Double
    
    Dim arg As Range, Data(), cValue
    Dim rCount As Long, cCount As Long, r As Long, c As Long
    Dim Result As Double, IsFirstFound As Boolean
    
    For Each arg In rg.Areas
        
        rCount = arg.Rows.Count
        cCount = arg.Columns.Count
        
        If rCount * cCount = 1 Then
            ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = arg.Value
        Else
            Data = arg.Value
        End If
        
        For r = 1 To rCount
            For c = 1 To cCount
                cValue = Data(r, c)
                If VarType(cValue) = vbDouble Then ' is a number
                    If cValue < 0 Then ' is a negative number
                        If IsFirstFound Then
                            If cValue > Result Then
                                Result = cValue
                            End If
                        Else ' initialize i.e. first negative value to 'Result'
                            Result = cValue
                            IsFirstFound = True
                        End If
                    'Else ' is not a negative number; do nothing
                    End If
                'Else ' is not a number; do nothing
                End If
            Next c
        Next r
    
    Next arg
        
    If IsFirstFound Then
        GetMaxNegative = Result
    'Else ' no negative values found; do nothing; 'GetMaxNegative = Result = 0'
    End If
 
End Function
```

Comment: This might be useful in future  ...  https://davetallett26.github.io/excel-markdown.html